# Data within assemble markdown helper?

Tags: assemble

I’ve been using assemble (`v0.24.3`) for a while now and have just noticed that a feature that previously worked now appears not to - namely being able to put [data](http://assemble.io/docs/Data.html) (such as `{{title}}`) inside of the [markdown helper](https://github.com/helpers/helper-markdown) that assemble provides.

Is there a way to do this in the latest version of assemble?

As a use case -  I used to use this to prefix site urls with a certain strings when pushing to github pages, as it needed a slightly more specific base url path, but now that data variable just looks like it gets ignored when rendered.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Which version of `assemble` or `grunt-assemble` are you using? How are you using the markdown helper in the template? What data are you passing in? It might be as simple as needing to do `{{../title}}` because the scope of the data is handled differently in newer versions of Handlebars.

Comment: Sorry, I should know better than to not include version numbers ;)

I was using `assemble` version `0.24.3` - but your suggestion of using `{{../title}}` was the issue.

If you add this as an answer I’ll mark that as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handlebars` will create a new "scope" or "depth" when the context inside a block helper is different than the surrounding context. In newer versions of `assemble`, the context is added from assemble data for use inside block helpers, which causes handlebars to create a new depth. To ensure that you're using the "parent" depth from inside the block helper, you should use the `{{../}}` syntax:

```
{{#markdown}}
# {{../title}}
{{/markdown}}
```